# invalid trigger specification in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

```
DROP TABLE a CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE a(
    cyear VARCHAR2(4));

CREATE TRIGGER current_year
BEFORE INSERT ON  cyear
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.year = year(NOW());
```

**EDIT:**

I tried this,

```
CREATE TRIGGER current_year
  BEFORE INSERT ON a
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.cyear = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY');
END current_year;
```

I keep getting the PLS-00103 error.

Comment: `:NEW.cyear := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY');`. It is not `=` but `:=` for assignment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Trigger created on tables, not on columns
2. In Oracle variables are not assigned with `SET`
3. There is no build-in function called `NOW` in Oracle
4. `NEW` and `OLD` are accessible only in `WHEN` clause; in other places they should be preceded by colon (`:NEW`, `:OLD`)
5. `END` keyword is missed at the end (and `BEGIN` in the beginning of the trigger body)